# Apache rewrite multi level virtual urls to a common HTML file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm not sure whether my question is valid...

**Problem:**
I have index.html and question.html

I want to redirect following urls to the following HTML files.

- site.com -> index.html
- site.com/question -> question.html
- site.com/question/how-to-code -> question.html
- site.com/question/coding-basics -> question.html
- site.com/question/coding-basics/view -> question.html

**Solutions tried:**
I used .htaccess file using below rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} question
RewriteRule .* question.html
```

Also like this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} question
RewriteRule "/question/(.*)$" "/question.html" [PT]
```

So far I'm only getting 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/question.html
RewriteRule ^question /question.html [L]
```